# Are there sanskrit verses for lingdharanam in shiv puran

Tags: shaivism, shiva-purana

Sanskrit verses for lingdharanam

Comment: Hi, welcome to Hinduism SE! can you please make it more clear, what do you mean by lingdharanam?